# Use Ninject in both main and referenced projects

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

I have MVC4 website project and WCF project, both using Ninject.

I want to use class from WCF project in website project. I add reference to project and get both `NinjectWebCommon.Start()` executing (with "The static container already has a kernel associated with it!" error).

Is there way to make what I want?

Comment: your question is not well clear. can you show your coding???

Comment: There is no my coding, only empty projects with installed ninject.web and added reference from one to other. May be need to use other kernel starting, not generated `[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(WcfService1.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using this startup in referenced project

```
public class Global : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        return new StandardKernel(new ServiceModule());
    }
}
```